# Room Database migration

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

How many methods will I have to make for Room migration if I have db version 10?

I looked into the following example [Google Persistence Migration Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceMigrationsSample/app/src/room3/java/com/example/android/persistence/migrations/UsersDatabase.java)

and I found *Migration* varargs based on probable scenarios for database version 4.

```
public static UsersDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    synchronized (sLock) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db") 
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3, MIGRATION_3_4, MIGRATION_1_4)
                    .build(); 
        } 
        return INSTANCE;
    } 
}
```

My question is, Suppose I am using Room from the db v1 and by time my app reaches to db v10, how many migration methods will I have to write?

In sqlite, we get current db version of installed app in `onUpgrade` and we just fall through switch case without break statements so that it satisfies all db upgrades.

However, I am not sure, but afaik, we cannot get current db version of installed app in room, we write all possible methods for migration.

But it feels so inconvenient, inappropriate to write total 45 methods if I have db v10!

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Suppose I am using Room from the db v1 and by time my app reaches to db v10, how many migration methods will I have to write?

9.

One approach is: 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5, 5->6, 6->7, 7->8, 8->9, and 9->10.

Another approach is: 1->10, 2->10, 3->10, ..., 9->10.

My guess is that the first approach is more popular, as it is easier to develop. For each new database release, you just create one additional object.

> In sqlite, we get current db version of installed app in onUpgrade and we just fall through switch case without break statements so that it satisfies all db upgrades.

That will be about the same number of lines of code, give or take, as what you would do in Room. Each one of your `case` statements gets turned into a `Migration` object, handling an incremental upgrade (e.g., 3->4).

> But it feels so inconvenient, inappropriate to write total 45 methods if I have db v10!

Room knows how to "stitch together" individual migrations as needed to reach a target version. So, in the first approach that I outlined, if an app needs to be migrated from 3 to 10, Room can use 3->4, 4->5, 5->6, ..., 9->10 to get there.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. However, what if I want to go back to previous version? For example, say I have APK 1 with db_v1 and APK 2 with db_v2. So, my clients are using APK 2 but for some reason they needed to go back to APK 1. How to handle such scenarios? Thank you.

Comment: @JuniaMontana: "How to handle such scenarios?" -- I have never looked into that. Sorry!

Comment: @juniaMontana: We are currently facing the same issue.  Our plan is to create a 1->2 and 2->1 script with each apk and store them cumulatively onto the tablet file system (we are a root application).  If you ever install APK 2, and then revert to APK 1, the 2->1 script will exist and the old code can revert the db without ever having to know anything about this "future" version.

Comment: @MarkBrown Did you use regular sql command to write the script? Do you mind sharing the idea please? Also, what is your plan for say, you have apk 5 and there's been changes in Database in between, so you had to increase the version accordingly, how are you handling the downgrade from apk 5 to 1? Thank you.

Comment: @JuniaMontana: Currently, "it's the plan" as we haven't written any code yet.  The scripts could contain just SQL commands or it could contain any number of actions we want to take.  The idea is that the migration step will load and parse the file, and then perform whatever actions we want to take, which is likely sql statements.  We plan to create a script for every increment, so we'll have 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5 as well as 5->4, 4->3, and so on, so Room Migrations should handle that one at a time.  We'll dynamically add as many migration objects as necessary for each step of the way.

Comment: @MarkBrown seems like it's the only option so far. I solved this issue the same way. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Just to circle back - we have implemented "the plan" as described above and everything is working nicely.  Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Write migrations to v10 from versions 1 to 9.

```
public static UsersDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
synchronized (sLock) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db") 
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_10, MIGRATION_2_10, MIGRATION_3_10, MIGRATION_4_10, .......)
                .build(); 
    } 
    return INSTANCE;
} 
}
```

Once you know your db schema you can migrate directly from v1 to v10, v2 to v10 and so on.